# Regex negative lookahead and word boundary removes first character from capture group

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, word-boundary

I am trying to capture every word in a string except for 'and'. I also want to capture words that are surrounded by asterisks like *this*. The regex command I am using mostly works, but when it captures a word with asterisks, it will leave out the first one (so *this* would only have this* captured). Here is the regex I'm using:

```
/((?!and\b)\b[\w*]+)/gi
```

When I remove the last word boundary, it will capture all of *this* but won't leave out any of the 'and' s.

Comment: what language are you regexing for?

Comment: Can you post a couple sample strings?

Comment: I'm writing for c#. Here is a sample string:

\*this\* and th\*at\*  --> this* th\*at*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `*` is not treated as a word character, so `\b` don't match a position before it. I think you can replace it with:

```
^(?!and\b)([\w*]+)|((?!and\b)(?<=\W)[\w*]+)
```

The \b was repleced with \W (non-word character) to match also `*`, however then the first word in string will not match because is not precedeed by non-word character. This is why I added alternative.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eG8uP2/2)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks m.cekiera.